# Call Form2 property in main form(Form1)

Tags: .net

I have tried others suggestion for using this type and somehow manage to run it, but now I have using the same way but having an error as

**Error :**'  FYP.Form6.listBox1' is inaccessible due to its protection level

I am enclosing code below

```
Form6 frm4 = new Form6(this.listbox1);

        for (int i=0;i<frm4.listBox1.Items.Count;i++)
        {
            // <P>
            xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("P");
            xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("","DISP","",frm4.listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
            xmlWriter.WriteString(frm4.listBox2.Items[i].ToString());
            // </P>
            xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess, the `Modifiers` property of `listBox1` control of the `Form6` form is set to 'private'. Up it to `internal` or `public`.

Comment: He is using     this.listbox1. So, does it really matter, if it has any access specifier.

Comment: `this.listbox1` might be used to populate listBox1 of Form6. The error throws at `frm4.listBox1` not `this.listbox1`. Anyway just my guess as we do not know what's going on in the constructor of `Form6(ListBox)`.:)